# How to get data from a js alert box into a label

Tags: javascript, label, alert

I simply want to display the data in the alert box as a label instead.

This is what I found and it works fine as an alert box:

```js
<script language="Javascript"  type="text/javascript" src="http://www.codehelper.io/api/ips/?js"></script>

<script language="Javascript"  type="text/javascript" >

    alert(codehelper_ip.IP);
    alert(codehelper_ip.CityName);
</script>
```

I have searched for quite some time and have found a wealth of information, none of which I have been able to make work.

I tried many snippets and played with many variations of those snippets yet I get either a compilation error or a blank screen.

There must be a relatively simple way of doing this, is there not?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Bob

I appreciate your replies.

Awolf and Allesandro, I've been able to use your code in my page and have it display a great deal of information. However, not quite what I was looking for.

Epascarello, I was able to click "Run Code Snippet" on the site here and got exactly what I was looking for. BUT, I can't seem to implement on my page.

You say it's basic Javascript and it may very well be, but js is not one of my strong suits. In fact I don't even have a JS suit.

I am unable to get a page to display what I need using your script, yet I'm sure it's what I need.

This, amongst many other variations is what I've tried:

```
<script language="Javascript"  type="text/javascript" src="http://www.codehelper.io/api/ips/?js">
document.getElementById("ip").innerHTML = codehelper_ip.IP;
document.getElementById("city").innerHTML = codehelper_ip.CityName;
</script>
<label id="ip"></label>
<label id="city"></label>
```

And yes I have included this:

```
<script language="Javascript"  type="text/javascript" src="http://www.codehelper.io/api/ips/?js">
```

What have I got in the wrong spot?

Thanks
Bob

Comment: What do you mean , show data as a label >  ? what label ?

Answer (score 0):

Basic JavaScript. Use getElementById to reference an element and set the object value into the element with innerHTML.

```js
document.getElementById("ip").innerHTML = codehelper_ip.IP;
document.getElementById("city").innerHTML = codehelper_ip.CityName;
```

```html
<script language="Javascript"  type="text/javascript" src="http://www.codehelper.io/api/ips/?js"></script>
<label id="ip"></label>
<label id="city"></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

see http://jsfiddle.net/alemarch/eko0u6jf/

```
<div id="info"></div>
<script>
  html="";
  for (x in codehelper_ip) {
     html += x +": " + codehelper_ip[x] + "<br>"
  }
  document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = html
</script>
```

or if you want only ip and CountryName

```
document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = codehelper_ip["IP"] +" "
document.getElementById("info").innerHTML += codehelper_ip["CountryName"] + " "
document.getElementById("info").innerHTML += '<img height=20 src="' + codehelper_ip["Flag"] + '">';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery you could use the data like in the demo below:

In this demo you see every key that is in the JSON object `codehelper_ip`.

Please notice that this is a synchronous request of data. It slows down your javascript execution / page loading a bit. I think that's no problem if it is your only synch. request.

But if you're having many js file that are loaded at initial page load, you should check if a asynchrounous ajax request is better.

(same here at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/tzqvsetq/))

```js
$(function() {
    //codehelper_ip;
    var $jsondata = $('<pre/>')
        .html(JSON.stringify(codehelper_ip, null, 2))
    var $IPadr = $('<p/>').text("Your IP address is: " + codehelper_ip.IP);
    
    $('body').append($jsondata, $IPadr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.codehelper.io/api/ips/?js"></script>
```